# Extract all MP3 and OGG Links from String with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i was trying to create a regular expressions to extract all MP3/OGG links from a example word but i could't! this is a example word that i'm trying to extract MP3/OGG files from it:

```
this is a example word http://domain.com/sample.mp3 and second file is https://www.mydomain.com/sample2.ogg. then this is a link for third file <a href="http://seconddomain.com/files/music.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

and PHP part:

```
$Word = "this is a example word http://domain.com/sample.mp3 and second file is https://www.mydomain.com/sample2.ogg. then this is a link for third file <a href="http://seconddomain.com/files/music.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>";


$Pattern = '/href=\"(.*?)\".mp3/';
preg_match_all($Pattern,$Word,$Matches);
print_r($Matches);
```

i tried this too:

```
$Pattern = '/href="([^"]\.mp3|ogg)"/';
$Pattern = '/([-a-z0-9_\/:.]+\.(mp3|ogg))/i';
```

so i need your help to fix this code and extract all MP3/OGG links from that example word.

Thank you guys.

Comment: What don't you want the first two links without the `href`?

Comment: i need all links, not only with href tags

Comment: my answer is not correct ? (?<=p1(.+)?)p2 match p2 if before matched p1 / what's wrong?

Comment: i'm still testing all this answers! give me a minute :D

Comment: ok, I'm just looking at all answer is upvoted... :) but not mine

Comment: i'm sorry my friend. your code is not working for me...

Comment: my answer is updated for php!
please, write for next time - what exactly does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all links, you can use:

```
((https?:\/\/)?(\w+?\.)+?(\w+?\/)+\w+?.(mp3|ogg))
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/38trl).

`((https?:\/\/)?` Optional `http://` or `https://`

`(\w+?\.)+?` Matches domain groups

`(\w+?\/)+` Matches the final domain group and forward slash

`\w+?.(mp3|ogg))` Matches a filename ending in `.mp3` or `.ogg`.

In the string you provided there are several unescaped quotation marks, when corrected and my regex added in:

```
$Word = "this is a example word http://domain.com/sample.mp3 and second file is https://www.mydomain.com/sample2.ogg. then this is a link for third file <a href=\"http://seconddomain.com/files/music.mp3\" target=\"_blank\">Download</a>";

$Pattern = '/((https?:\/\/)?(\w+?\.)+?(\w+?\/)+\w+?.(mp3|ogg))/im';
preg_match_all($Pattern,$Word,$Matches);
var_dump($Matches[0]);
```

Produces the following output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'http://domain.com/sample.mp3' (length=28)
  1 => string 'https://www.mydomain.com/sample2.ogg' (length=36)
  2 => string 'http://seconddomain.com/files/music.mp3' (length=39)
```

Comment: @Alireza See my edits with a working implementation.

Comment: thank you my friend, but with you code, i'm getting nothing in my project! i don't know why!

Comment: @Alireza Are you sure the code is being executed? It runs as expected on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: yes, i'm sure! this is a full CMS! the only part that is not working is your code!

Comment: @Alireza Is there an `ob_start();` call before you try and run this which could be capturing it?

Comment: i'm trying to fix it. thank for your time my friend.

Answer (score 1):

> ..extract all MP3/OGG links from that example word.

e.g.:

```
(?<=https?://(.+)?)\.(mp3|ogg)
```

- $1 - uri
- $2 - extension

**Updated:**

:( yes, on the PHP *(v5.5 tested)* search with:

```
(?<=https?://(.+)?)\.(mp3|ogg)
```

there are restrictions:

- Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not **fixed length** at offset n

so, the similar variant:

- `(?<=p1(.+)?)p2` - match p2 if matched p1 before
- `p2(?=(.+)p3)` - match p2 if matched p3 after  - all working with not fixed length ~ **.+?** for PHP

for your sample:

```
//p2(?=.*p3)
preg_match_all("#https?://(?=(.+?)\.(mp3|ogg))#im", $Word, $Matches);

/*
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://
        [1] => https://
        [2] => http://
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => domain.com/sample
        [1] => www.mydomain.com/sample2
        [2] => seconddomain.com/files/music
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => mp3
        [1] => ogg
        [2] => mp3
    )
 */
```